# Selecting elements with a certain background color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to select a bunch of `span`s in a `div` whose CSS contains a particular background color. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

if i understand the question correctly, the selector `[attribute=value]` **will not work** because `<span>` does not contain an attribute "background-color". you can test that out quickly to confirm it won't match anything:

```
$('#someDiv span[background-color]').size(); // returns 0
```

given:

```
.one, .two {
  background-color: black;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
}
```

here's a snippet that **will work**:

```js
$('div#someDiv span').filter(function() {
    var match = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'; // match background-color: black
    /*
        true = keep this element in our wrapped set
        false = remove this element from our wrapped set
                                                         */
    return ( $(this).css('background-color') == match );

}).css('background-color', 'green'); // change background color of all black spans
```

```css
.one, .two {
  background-color: black;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="someDiv">
    <span class="one">test one</span>
    <span class="two">test two</span>
    <span class="three">test three</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do the same thing for an elements ID? And if you have 5 of the same id's on the same page, how would you match them, assign a background, and then find other matching ID's that would do the same?

Comment: @Tom That's kinda tricky because well, you shouldn't have 5 ids. An id should be unique on that page, and having more than one will not work well with javascript (I believe it just grabs the first one it finds). Are you able to convert them to classes?

Comment: It worked for me. with a minor change. The color codes when I inspect  are shown in RGB but when the code run, #XXXXXX works.$(document).ready( function () /*run script after DOM is ready */ {
  $('#MyId tr').each(function() {
   var yellowmatch = '#ffffcc';
      var redmatch = '#ffd7d7';
   var greenmatch = '#e1ffe1';
   if($(this).css('background-color') == redmatch )
   {
   }
   if($(this).css('background-color') == yellowmatch)
   {
   }
   if($(this).css('background-color') == greenmatch )
   {
   }
  });
    });</script>

Comment: @owen nice solution!

`css('background-color');` can also return rgba...

`var match = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'; //black with 50% alpha`

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript Approach

1. Get all spans
2. Convert spans nodelist to array
3. Filter spans array
4. Change the background color of matched span elements

```js
// Get all spans
let spans = document.querySelectorAll('div#someDiv span'); 

// Convert spans nodeslist to array
spans = Array.from( spans ); 

// Filter spans array
// Get CSS properties object of selected element - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
let arr = spans.filter( span => String( document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( span, null ).backgroundColor ) == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' );

// Change background color of matched span elements
arr.forEach( span => {
    span.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
});
```

```css
.one, .two {
  background-color: black;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="someDiv">
    <span class="one">test one</span>
    <span class="two">test two</span>
    <span class="three">test three</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still tired of writing procedures for selecting something?
Here is the general procedure for selecting anything. You don't have to write another procedure for select anywhere. Try it, this is example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script>

function ReplaceAll(base,told,tnew) { // replace insensitive
  if (told=="") {return base;}
  var u=base.toLowerCase();
  var t=told.toLowerCase();
  var ss=""; var p=-1; var i=0;
  p=u.indexOf(t);
  if (p>-1) {
    let mLen=told.length;
    while (p>=0) {
      ss+=base.substr(0,p)+tnew;
      i=p+mLen;
      base=base.substr(i);
      u=u.substr(i);
      p=u.indexOf(t);
    }
    ss+=base; //fix bug
    return ss;
  }
  return base;
}

function Len(pS) {return pS.length;}
function Lower(pS) {return pS.toLowerCase();}
function Upper(pS) {return pS.toUpperCase();}
function Trim(pS) {return pS.trim();}
function Sub(pS, p1, p2=0) { 
  if (p2<=0) {p2=Len(pS);}
  if (p1<=0) {p1=0;}
  return pS.substring(p1,p2); 
}
  

function IndexAt(base, t ,pos=0) { //index from position
  if (pos<0) {pos=0;}
  var x=base.substr(pos);
  var p=x.indexOf(t);
  if (p>=0) { return p+pos;} else {return -1;}
}

function NormStyle(pS) {  //normalization style
  pS=Trim(pS);
  if (Len(pS)==0) {
    return pS;
  }
  if (IndexAt(pS,":")>=0) {pS+=";";} // style+";"
  pS=ReplaceAll(pS,';;',';');
  pS=ReplaceAll(pS,' ','');  // without spaces!  -> font-name
  pS=ReplaceAll(pS,',',', ');
  //-- color:#* ->color:rgb(*), because jQuery in runtime replace style: color:#* -> rgb(*), font_size:?em -> ?px .. etc.
  var p1=0; var p2=0;
  var t1=""; var t2="";
  p1=IndexAt(pS,"color:#");
  while (p1>=0) {
   p2=IndexAt(pS,';',p1);
   if (p2>0) {
     t1=Sub(pS,p1,p2); //color:#ff0000
     t2=Sub(t1,6); //#ff0000
     t2=RGB(t2);
     pS=ReplaceAll(pS,t1,"color:"+t2);
   }
   p1=IndexAt(pS,"color:#",p0+2);
  }
  return pS;
}

function RGB(pS) {
  var rgb=pS;
  if (IndexAt(Trim(rgb),"#")==0) {
    rgb=Trim(rgb);
    rgb=rgb.padEnd(7,"0"); //#ff00 -> #ff00000
    var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
    var matches = patt.exec(rgb);
    rgb = "rgb("+parseInt(matches[1], 16)+", "+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+", "  +parseInt(matches[3], 16)+")";
  }
  return rgb;
}

function NQ(pS) { //NQ("alfa 'b`c' x")=="alfa ♣♣♣♣♦ x"
  var bo=false; var mEnd=true; 
  var typ=0;
  var s="";
  for (let i=0; i<Len(pS); i++) {
    switch (pS.charAt(i)) {
     case '"': if (typ==1) {typ=0;} else { if (typ==0) {typ=1;} } break;
     case "'": if (typ==2) {typ=0;} else { if (typ==0) {typ=2;} } break;
     case "`": if (typ==3) {typ=0;} else { if (typ==0) {typ=3;} } break;
    }
    if (typ==0) {
      if (!mEnd) { mEnd=true; s+="♦"} else {s+=pS.charAt(i);} 
    } else {
      s+="♣"; mEnd=false;
    } 
  }
  if (typ>0) {s="Error:♣ Not valid string termination";}
  return s;
}

function Element(pSelector, pFilter="",pNumbers="",pTrace=1) { //pTrace: 0=no trace, 1=console.log, 2=alert trace
  switch (pTrace) {
   case 1: console.log("start trace"); break; 
   case 2: alert("start trace"); break;
  }
  //--- pNumbers ---
  
  pNumbers=Trim(pNumbers);
  var  mNumbers=""
  if (pNumbers>"") { mNumbers = "," + pNumbers + ","; }
  //--- pFilter validation for eval --- // Assignment(=) is not allowed
  pFilter=Trim(pFilter);
  if (pFilter>"") {
    let s=ReplaceAll(pFilter,"===","♠♠♠"); 
    s=ReplaceAll(s,"==","♠♠"); 
    if (IndexAt(s,"=")>0) {
      s=NQ(s);
      if (s=="Error:♣ Not valid string termination") {
        if (pTrace==1) {console.log(s+" pFilter:"+pFilter);} 
        alert(s); 
        return null;
      } else {
        if (IndexAt(s,"=")>0) { 
          let x="Error: Assignment is not allowed (=/==)";
          if (pTrace==1) {console.log(x+", "+s);} 
          alert(x+"\n"+s);
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  var mCnt=0;

  var mObj=$(pSelector).filter(function(){
    var bo=true; 
    var s=""; var t=""; var ss="";
    mCnt++;
    //--- pNumbers --
    if (mNumbers>"") {
      t=","+mCnt+",";
      if (IndexAt(mNumbers,t)<0) { 
        bo=false; 
      }
    }
    //-----RESULT by pNumbers ---
    if (pNumbers>"" && pTrace>0) {
      if ( !bo || (bo && pFilter=="") ) {
        switch (pTrace) {
          case 1: console.log(mCnt+". Result by numbers: "+bo+", numbers:["+pNumbers+"]"); break; 
          case 2: alert(mCnt+". Result by numbers: " +bo+", numbers:["+pNumbers+"]"); break;
        }
      }
    }

    //-------- pFilter ----
    if (bo && pFilter>"") {
      var cPrefix="{:"; var cSufix="}";
      var p1=0; var p2=0; var p3=0;
      var t1=""; var t2=""; var t3=""; var t4=""
      var r1=""; var r2="";
      var lenP=Len(cPrefix); var lenS=Len(cSufix);
      s=pFilter; ss=s;
      p1=IndexAt(s,cPrefix);
       
      while (p1>=0) {
        r1=""; p2=IndexAt(s,cSufix,p1);
        if (p2>=0) {
          t1=Sub(s,p1,p2+1)  //{:css.color} //{:html}
          t2=Sub(t1,lenP); //css.color} //html}
          t2=Sub(t2,0,Len(t2)-lenS); //css.color //html
          t2=Lower(t2);
          p3=IndexAt(t2,".");
          if (p3>0) {
            t3=Sub(t2,0,p3);  //css
            t4=Sub(t2,p3+1);  //color
            r1='$(this).'+t3+'("'+t4+'")';  //$(this).css("color")
            if (t3=='attr' && t4=='style') {
              r1='NormStyle(String($(this).attr("style"))';//exception for attr.style, because jQuery in runtime change attr style
            }
          } else {
            r1='$(this).'+t2+'()';  //html -> $(this).html()      
            if (t2=="data") {r1='JSON.stringify('+r1+')';} //exemption for data -> JSON.stringify( $(this).data() )
          }
        }
        if (t1>"" && r1>"") {s=ReplaceAll(s, t1, r1);}
        //--- evaluate only in trace mode for debug ---
        if (pTrace>0) {  
          r2=eval(r1);
          ss=ReplaceAll(ss,t1,"'"+r2+"'");
        }  
        //---  next iterate --- 
        p1=IndexAt(s,cPrefix,p1+2); 
      } 
      //  --- trace1 ---
      if (ss>"" && pTrace>0) {
        switch (pTrace) { 
          case 1: console.log(mCnt+". "+ss); break; 
          case 2: alert(mCnt+". "+ss); break; 
        }
      }
      //--- evaluate ---
      bo=eval(s);
      // --- trace2 ---
      switch (pTrace) {
        case 1: console.log(mCnt+". FILTER: "+bo+", [:"+s+"]"); break; 
        case 2: alert(mCnt+". FILTER: "+bo+"\n ["+s+"]"); break; 
      }
    }
    //--- RESULT ---
    return bo;
  })

  switch (pTrace) {
    case 1: console.log("end trace"); break; 
    case 2: alert("end trace"); break;
  }
  return mObj;   
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var mObj=Element("body p a",
                     "{:css.color}==RGB('#ff00') && {:css.font-size}=='16px' && 'href='+{:attr.href} > '' ",
                     "2,3"
                    );
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(mObj)) {mObj.hide();}  // or mObj.css('display','none')
  /* 
    // --- hidden element only from selector ":hidden"
    mObj=Element('a:hidden');
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(mObj)) {mObj.show();}
  */
  
  /*
   //css.
    {:css.color} -> $(this).css("color")
    {:css.font-size} -> $(this).css("font-size")
    {:css.display}-> $(this).css("display")
   //attr.
    {:attr.href} -> $(this).attr("href")+"]"+
  * {:attr.style} -> NormStyle(String($(this).attr("style"))
    {:attr.id} -> $(this).attr("id")
    {attr.class -> $(this).attr("class")
   //spec
    {:html} -> $(this).html()
    {:index} -> $(this).index()
  * {:data} -> JSON.stringify($(this).data())
    {val} -> $(this).val()) // for value //or prop.value
   //prop    
    {:prop.checked} -> $(this).prop("checked")
    {:prop.selected} -> $(this).prop("selected")
    {:prop.selectedIndex} -> $(this).prop("selectedIndex")
    {:prop.disabled} -> $(this).prop("disabled")
   //comment 
    prop() for:  
      disabled,checked,selected,value,selectedIndex,tagName,nodeName,nodeType,ownerDocument,defaultChecked 
    val() for value 
  */

  });
});
      
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>jQuery.Element() for filtering "any"</h2>
<p>
  <a id="1" href="?m=1" style="color:#ff0000;font-size:16px;" class="alpha" data-x="123" data-y="123">1. ALPHA</a>
  , <a id="2" style="color:#ff0000;font-size:16px;">2. BETA </a>
  , <a id="3" href="?m=3" style="font-size:16px;">3. GAMMA</a>
</p>
<a id="4" href="?m=4" style="font-size:14px;">END</a>
<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: function Element(pSelector, pFilter="",pNumbers="",pTrace=1)  // pTrace:  0=no trace, 1=console.log, 2=alert trace

Answer (score -7):

Use the attribute selector [attribute=value] to look for a certain attribute value.

```
#id_of_the_div span[background-color=rgb(255,255,255)]
```

Comment: this will not work because background-color is a css property and not a html property