# How to choose all the elements of INPUT?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to choose all the elements of INPUT with style="color: #F20808"?

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="2" style="color: #F20808">
<input type="text" value="3" style="color: #F20808">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

$('form').submit(function(){
    if($(this).find('input').css('color') != 'rgb(242, 8, 8)'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
});


This way works, but I dont like:
$('form').submit(function(){
    if($(this).find('input:eq(1), input:eq(2)').css('color') != 'rgb(242, 8, 8)'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
});
```

Are there any other ways?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery css selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/jquery-css-selectors)

Comment: I couldn't make it work, could you pass a jsfiddle.net, thx. I only made it work as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input[style*="color: #F20808"]
```

should work as CSS3 or JQuery selector.

Comment: You need to wrap `color: #F20808` in quotes.

Comment: Even if it makes sense, I didn't make it work. http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/hSyqH/

Comment: @MatThecat: you can see it in the jsfiddle.net page

Comment: Did you take care of quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/mUxbG/)

Here you have a solution, it will select all the inputs with a style attribute:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        alert($("input[style*=color][type*=text]").length);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        alert($('input[style*="color: rgb(242, 8, 8)"]').length);
       return false;    
    });
```