# select and edit All css elements by jquery

Tags: jquery, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting elements with a certain background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color)

how to edit all elements css using  jquery that use color or background #333

And changing all to color or backgroundColor #000

TanX from All

Comment: Duplicate .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/282198/555384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not simply an attribute selector - finding elements whose colours are set via class names or IDs requires that you write code to loop through the elements checking the background colour of each.

See: [Selecting elements with a certain background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color)