# javascript: I need to convert text-color of the element by background-color, any advises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, converters

I have div element with background-color: red; so I need to set text-color of div div into a convert(my DIV's background-color), is there any plugins or functions to make it easy? JQuery or JavaScript, hope they do.

Comment: You want to do what to the text color?

Comment: convert him into contrary color, for example div has black background-color, text-color must be white, and overturn, if div's background white, so text-color must be black, and it must works with any colors not only black/white.

Comment: Do you mean you want some code to find out what is the inverse color?

Comment: your question seems similar to the following one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var div = $("#my_div");
div.css({color:div.css("background-color")})
```

Comment: If you have hex colors you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664140/js-function-to-calculate-complementary-color