# How to select list item by color

Tags: list, colors, comparison-operators

I would like to get the id of any item in my list that with a certain text color, in this example rgb(255,0,0). Everything works up until the if statement. Is there something I need to know about the comparison operator and colors?

```
$('.jqshow li').click(function() {
$('.jqshow li').attr('style', 'color:black');
$(this).attr('style','color:rgb(255,0,0)');
$('.jqshow li').each(function(i){
  var getcolor = $(this).css('color');
  if(getcolor != 'rgb(255,0,0)') {
    var getid = $(this).attr('id')
    alert(getid);
}
})  
    })
```

Comment: I think, your question was already answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color

Comment: san.chez, it's definitely duplicate.