# Replace everytime this color by that color in css with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, colors, replace

I have a lot of `div`s, some of them have a `background-color: #aaa`, others have font `color: #aaa`, and others `border-color: #aaa`. Other `div`s have different colors, it doesn't matter.

I want to change these colors (`#aaa`) to `#ccc` everywhere in the CSS.
I know how to change a background `div` color but here this is not the problem, I have too many `div`s to change them one by one.

I'm trying to find a jQuery function which will allow me to find a word (here `#aaa`) and replace it by with other (`#ccc`) in the CSS.

It should be like that but my code isn't correct :

```
$("*").if(backgroundColor == "#aaa"){replace by "#ccc"},
if(color == "#aaa"){replace by "#ccc"}, if(borderColor == "#aaa"){replace by "#ccc"}, etc..
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to find and replace this in CSS with a text editor for example, or to do it live each time with JS/JQuery?

Comment: Not for text editor, I explain. On my web page I have a button "Change color" and I want to change the color of my web site by clicking on this button. It requires that the css page changes. I'm trying to create a jquery function that do this changes in the css.

Comment: Ah ok. Got you now. Are you trying to change all the elements in the page or just one section?

Comment: All in the page. I want to replace #aaa by #ccc everywhere in the page.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color

Comment: @RayCheng: Well hell!

Answer (score 5):

You want to iterate over all the elements of the type you want (in this case I picked `div` since it’s super common) and assign the color dynamically like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="one">Some text</div>
<div id="two">Some text</div>
<div id="three">Some text</div>
<div id="four">Some text</div>
<div id="change">
    <input type="button" value="Change Colors!" />
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#change").click(function () {
    $("div").each(function () {
        var color = $(this).css("color");
        if (color == "rgb(170, 170, 170)") {
            $(this).css("color", "#ccc");
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE: JQuery `.css()` returns an RGB color value like rgb(r, g, b) so you need to convert the returned RGB value to a HEX value. This can be done programatically but is outside the scope of this question.**

**CSS:**

```
#one, #two {
    color: #aaa;
}
#three, #four {
    color: green;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hQkk3/44/

Comment: But this code will change div which don't have color #aaa at the beggining ! Imagine div 1 and div 2 have color #aaa but div 3 and div 4 have color #888, I only want to change div 1 and 2 to #ccc, but i want #888 to stay #888. This is why I have to check the color of div at the beggining.

Comment: When I said "All in the page" i tried to say "All div which have #aaa color in the page" but not "All div in the page".

Comment: It seems to be good, but it's not finished. I don't only want to check div but ul, li, img, a, etc... Can i do $("div,ul,li,a,img,...").each(function () {...}}); ? And after that I try to find not only color but backgroundcolor or border color in div, ul, li,etc .. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can plugin whatever element you want for `div`. I just used `div` as an example.

Comment: using $("*")  instead of $("div") will allow searching of all elements on the page.