# How do I iterate through div's child elements and hide them?

Tags: javascript

I have a div that have a few elements that I want to hide, on users request. Those elements have a particular background color. The call of the function is working (it is associated to a checkbox) but it just doesnt do what i want. Actually, it does nothing. This is what I've got:

```
function toogleDisplay()
{
    var kiddos= document.getElementById('external-events').childNodes; //my div 
    for(i=0; i < kiddos.length; i++)
    {       
        var a=kiddos[i];
        if (a.style.backgroundColor=="#A2B5CD")
            {
            if (a.style.display!="none")        

            {
                a.style.display='none';
            }               
             else
             {
                a.style.display='block';
             }
         }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a jQuery object?

Comment: `var a=$(kiddos[i]);` - Random bit of jQuery there probably isnt helping. Try changing to `var a=kiddos[i];`

Comment: why the `$` in `$(kiddos[i])` ?

Comment: oh god, i feel stupid now...

Comment: I removed the jquery bit. Still not working.

Comment: looping through a collection you need to find what nodes are not elements else just put all the divs on one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for another aproach, using the idea of Kalel Wade. All the elements that may be (or not) hidden, already had a class name, which were the same for all elements, fortunately.

here comes the code

```
function toogleDisplay()
{

    var kiddos = document.getElementsByClassName("external-event ui-draggable");
    for (var i = 0, len = kiddos.length; i < len; i++) {
        var a=kiddos[i];
        if (a.style.backgroundColor==="rgb(162, 181, 205)")
            {
            if (a.style.display!="none")        
                {
                    a.style.display='none';
                }               
             else
                 {
                    a.style.display='block';
                 }
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

An element's background colour is converted to `rgb()` (or `rgba()`) format internally.

But that aside, assuming `$` is jQuery (you haven't tagged your question so I don't know!) then `a` is a jQuery object, which does not have a `style` property. It looks like you just wanted `var a = kiddos[i];`.

It is more reliable to use a specific class name instead.

Comment: I added that jquery by mistake. I dont want to use jquery for this little bit of code. I'll try the rgb thing.

Answer (score 1):

You re wrapping your `kiddos[i]` in a jquery-object `$(kiddos[i])` and **then** try to access the normal properties of a html-dom-objekt.
You have 2 possibilities:

- remove the `$()`
- use jquery-access to the properties

  ```
  a.css('display', none); // or just a.hide();
  ```

Additionally you cant check for '#123456' since the color is transformed. Check (@Niet the Dark Absol)s answer for this

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a class to the elements you want to check. Then instead of trying to use background, you can do

```
$(kiddos[i]).hasClass('myclass')
```

or for a very efficient way, you can do it in one line of code.

```
function toogleDisplay()
{
    $('.myclass').toggle(); //this will toggle hide/show
}
```

The divs would look like this

```
<div class='myclass'>Content</div>
```

EDIT - to do it without modifying existing html. I also think the rbg color should be rgb(162, 181, 205) if im not mistaken.
You can try something like this. Its based off the following link
[Selecting elements with a certain background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color)

```
function toogleDisplay()
{
$('div#external-events').filter(function() {
    var match = 'rgb(162, 181, 205)'; // should be your color
    return ( $(this).css('background-color') == match );
}).toggle()
}
```

Comment: this is a valid answer but not in my particular case. the code that generates the html is legacy, and I'm not particularly confident in editing it. Also, they already have a class defined, and by changing it, it may cause some unknown issues.

Comment: I completely understand. "Don't fix something that's not broken".

Comment: I actually folowed your suggestion of using the class of the elements and got something pretty similar. All the child elements of the div already had the same class name (the ones I wanted to hide and the ones i didnt want to hide). I used a pure javascript function to achive the result i needed, thou. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selection of a is causing issues. Unwrap the $() from that and you should be fine.

Also you could end up selecting text nodes that wont have a style property. You should check that the style property exists on the node before trying to access background, display, etc.

Use a class instead of a background and check for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to see if the 'nodeType' is an element 'a.nodeType == 1' see [Node.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) then it will work over multiple lines

```
var kiddos= document.getElementById('external-events').childNodes; //my div 
for(i=0; i < kiddos.length; i++)
{   
var a=kiddos[i];
 if (a.nodeType == 1){   // Check the node type

    if (a.style.backgroundColor=="red")
        {
        if (a.style.display!="none")        

        {
            a.style.display='none';
        }               
         else
         {
            a.style.display='block';
         }
     }

}
}
```