# Part 2. Select and Change elements with a certain background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Going off this question: [Selecting elements with a certain background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color)

I wanted to change the background of ALL elements with background of a certain color. I tried the method mentioned in the answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

---

### jQuery:

```
// using string
$('*').filter(function(){
    return ( $(this).css('background-color') == 'green' );
}).css('background', 'blue');
```

---

```
// using hex
$('*').filter(
    return ( $(this).css('background') == '#a3a3a3' );
}).css('background', 'red');
```

---

Here's the 
[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/baziwen/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert hex to RGB first and then compare

**Example**

```
<script>
    function hexToRgb(hex) {
        var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
        var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
        var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
        var b = bigint & 255;

        return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    }

    $('*').filter(function () {
        return ($(this).css('background-color') == hexToRgb('a3a3a3'));
    }).css('background', 'green');
</script>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suryagahlot/as85Lckd/)**