# How to select an element that has a specific property using only css?

Tags: html, css

Is there is any CSS selector that allows me to select elements that have a specific property, for example a red color?

Comment: Please post a code snippet for your example. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp... i.e p[color='red']

Comment: There are no selector that matches CSS properties. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors. If you mean HTML ATTRIBUTES, that's different and you have the attribute selectors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282198/selecting-elements-with-a-certain-background-color...This might help you.

Comment: no there is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript or Jquery

Example:

```
if(document.getElementById("yourID").style.color=="#ffffff"){
   return true;
}
#or Jquery
$("p").css("color");
```

Comment: is it valid for every property exist in css?